# Why does scroll view continue to scroll in nothingness?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-scrollview

In my app there is a `ConstraintLayout` in a `scrollView` but i'm having an issue with the `ConstrainLayout` height, i mean if i put the height to 0 or wrap_content or something like 420dp that remain invariable and so the scroll view continue to scroll the `ConstraintLayout` also if there is no content.

here is a releated screenshot:

[image]

**UPDATE FULL XML CODE**

[XML CODE HERE](https://github.com/UAiGorMan/XMLCodes/blob/master/XmL) i had to upload it to github because it's a bit long...

Comment: if the ScrollView is the parent of ConstraintLayout why are you setting ConstraintLayout layout params to the ScrollView?

Comment: @lelloman look better to the screenshot, it's not the unique ConstraintLayout.

Comment: you're setting vertical constraint for your scrollview, why giving it fixed height of 520dp? set it to 0dp so that it will match its parent

Comment: please post the code in the question there is no need to use external links

Comment: @lelloman with setting it to 520dp i'm doing a trick by hidding the fade effect from the scrollview and it's just a reason of the graphic.

Comment: @lelloman it's GitHub i can't post the whole code because it's longer than stackoverflow permise to post.

Answer (score 1):

**you are giving static hight to your scroll view because of this reason your scroll view scrolling**

make your **scroll view hight** `android:layout_height="520dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` **or** `android:layout_height="match_parent"` like this

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
>
```

Comment: Nothing is changing because the **scrollView** is going to wrap the **ConstraintView** so it's still remain invariable...

Comment: Actually the real problem it's not with the scrollView but with the ConstrainView, look better at the screenshot please.

Comment: @I.Mytyuk than provide your whole xml layout file

Answer (score 0):

set your scrollview height width to match_parent and fillViewPort to true.

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"/>
```